# Are there infinity many $n$ that can't be represented as sum of two composite numbers relatively prime to each other

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $a$ and $b$ be composite integers relatively prime to each other.

> Can it be shown that
>
> There are infinity many positive integers $n$ that can't be represented as
>
> $$n=a+b$$

Example first $n$ which can represent $13=9+4$

---

*Update* Now posted to MO [link](https://mathoverflow.net/q/354215/149083)

Comment: The largest number I found so far which has no such representation is $\ 210\ $. Upto $\ 10^4\ $, there is no larger $\ n\ $, I currently search upto $\ n=10^5\ $

Comment: If $\ n\ $ is a large number and we choose $\ a\ $ arbitary, such that it is smaller and coprime to $\ n\ $ , we have a good chance to have found a representation. Since upto $\ 10^5\ $ , the largest number having no such representation , is $\ 210\ $, it probably is the largest such number.

Comment: It is obvious that infinite many numbers $\ n\ $ have such a representation, for example every number of the form $$2^a+3^b$$ with $\ a,b\ $ integers greater than $\ 1\ $

Comment: @Peter thanks for comment and observations :)

Answer (score 1):

http://oeis.org/A096076 is the sequence, "Not the sum of two relatively prime composite numbers." It's given as,

$1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 14, 15, 16, 18, 20, 21, 22, 24, 26, 27, 28, 30, 32, 36, 38, 40, 42, 45, 48, 50, 54, 56, 60, 66, 70, 72, 78, 80, 84, 90, 96, 105, 108, 110, 120, 126, 132, 138, 140, 150, 180, 210.$

It says, 
"Max Alekseyev showed that this sequence is finite; proof completed by several people to show that the list is complete."

No proof is given, nor any link to a proof.

Comment: Can you give me any suggestions to generalize given problem  or to study such type of questions

Comment: Sorry, nothing comes to mind. Do you have Richard Guy's book, Unsolved Problems In Number Theory?

Comment: No, I'll buy it soon ...

Answer (score 0):

Answer is given by *GH from MO*

[Link for original answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/354239/149083)

Following fedja's comment, the number of decomposition $n=a+b$ with $\gcd(a,b)=1$ equals $\varphi(n)$. Among these, there are at most $2\pi(n)$ decompositions in which $a$ or $b$ is prime, hence $n$ has a suitable decomposition when $\varphi(n)>2\pi(n)$. Now the well-known explicit lower bounds for $\varphi(n)$ and upper bounds for $\pi(n)$ imply an explicit finite list of exceptions. For more details, see the relevant Wikipedia articles ([link1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function) and [link2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function)), or Rosser-Schoenfeld: Approximate formulas for some functions of prime numbers (1961).

**Added.** By (3.6) and (3.42) in the paper of Rosser and Schoenfeld, the inequality $\varphi(n)>2\pi(n)$ holds as long as
$$e^\gamma\log\log n+\frac{2.51}{\log\log n}<\frac{\log n}{2.52}.$$
In particular, $\varphi(n)>2\pi(n)$ holds for $n>10^7$.