# There are infinitely many $n\ne 2u+3v$ where $(u,v)=1$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Can it be shown that

There are infinitely many $n\in\mathbb{Z}_+$ which can **not** be written as $n=2u+3v$ where $u,v \in\mathbb{Z}_+$ with $\gcd(u,v)=1$?

$n=\{1,2,3,4,6,10,\cdots\}$

Or there are only $\{1,2,3,4,6,10\}$?

---

Edit: related post, [Are there infinity many $n$ that can't be represented as sum of two composite numbers relatively prime to each other](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3556923/647719)

Now posted to MO [link](https://mathoverflow.net/q/354215/149083)

Comment: Do you know about Bèzout identity?

Comment: @user715522 Now I'm looking on wiki

Answer (score 4):

All natural numbers greater than $10$ can be expressed in the required form. The following lists the different possibilities modulo $12$.

$$12k=(6k-3)\times2+2\times 3$$
$$12k+4=(6k-1)\times 2+2\times3$$
$$12k+6=(6k-3)\times 2+4\times3$$
$$12k+10=(6k-1)\times 2+4\times3$$

$$6k+1=2\times2+(2k-1)\times 3$$
$$6k+3=3k\times2+1\times 3$$
$$3k+2=1\times2+k\times 3$$

Comment: Thanks Maybe we only need to extend it to $p$ modulo $12$ with $(p,12)=1$.

Comment: En efecto, $\mathbb Z=2\mathbb Z+3\mathbb Z$ (by Bézout because $(2,3)=1$) so also the natural less than $10$ for example $1=3\cdot1+2(-1)$, etc.

Comment: Yes, however don't you want $u,v$ to be positive integers?

Comment: Note also that you cannot simply apply Bezout's identity because you have to ensure that the solutions $u,v$ are coprime.